# Bind enabled property of WPF user control to child controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have a UserControl with one or more child controls on it.

How can I disable those child controls when the UserControl is disabled, and enable them when it is enabled? My UserControl does not have a ViewModel, but is simply using the code-behind because it is quite simple.

I attempted to do something like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <ListBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" >
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is entirely unnecessary. When a parent element is disabled, its child elements are automatically disabled too.

Comment: @Clemens I agree totally.
@ian93 Bind the `UserControl` and `ListBox(es)` to the same property.

Comment: @arcticwhite No, do not bind the ListBox's IsEnabled property at all.

Comment: @Clemens Yes I agree he should not do that, but if he wants that type of solution he can do it.

Answer (score 0):

On your ListBox's `ItemContainerStyle` add a binding

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="{Binding Path=IsEnabled,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was how to disable the ListBox when the parent UserControl is disabled. Besides that it is not necessary at all. When a ListBox is disabled, all íts ListBoxItems are disabled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what my mistake was.

I was trying to bind the IsEnabled property on the instance of the UserControl to a value in my datacontext.

However, when binding to a UserControl, you have to do something like this:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsWatermarkEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
```

This solved the problem.